# IndexError: why does this happen?

Tags: python-3.x, list, index-error

I am trying to figure this out and searched for an answer but still stuck. I know the list starts with 0. The question here is how come X prints Opel but Y gives indexerror?

```
cars = ['Volvo', 'Opel', 'BMW']
numbers1 = {1, 2, 3, X, 6}
numbers2 = {Y, 2, 3, 4, 7}
print(cars[X])
print(cars[Y])
```

Comment: Its a list, not a dictionary and also ```X``` prints ```Opel``` for you, it maybe cuz of some pre-compiled code in the same file, check it out..

Comment: Thanks alot! at top it was written X = 1 and Y = 4
So easy yet i couldnt see it

Comment: Are `numbers1` and `numbers2` relevant to the problem?

Comment: NVM, after reading the comments, the solution was trivial, so I'm voting to close the question. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. For debugging questions in the future, please provide a [mre] including complete code with irrelevant parts removed, and the full error message including traceback.